# Equation of an exponential function from the Graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The equation of any exponential function is given by:

$$y = a \cdot  b ^{(x-h)} + k,$$

where the value of $k$ can be found directly from the graph (as it's the horizontal asymptote), even if the parent function and multiplier is not known.

However, no one has been able to tell us how to find the value of $h$ directly from the graph if the parent function $b$ and multiplier $a$ is not known ?

Kindly help us. We shall be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that $h$ could be any number since $$y = a \cdot  b ^{(x-h)} + k=\frac{a}{b^h} b^x+k$$ So, if you do not know $a$, I do not think that you can get $h$.

Notice that you can get $b$ easily using two data points since you know $k$. Working the ratio, you could find $$\frac{y_2-k}{y_1-k}=b^{x_2-x_1}$$ May be, an easier way to understand the problem is to write $$y-k=a \cdot b^{x-h}$$ Take the logarithm $$\log(y-k)=\log(a)+(x-h)\log(b)=\big(\log(a)-h \cdot\log(b)\big)+b \cdot \log(x)$$ So, for a given $k$ and a given $b$ and a given graph $\big(\log(a)-h \cdot\log(b)\big)$ is a constant; you can select any $a$ and get the corresponding $h$.